# Mi función de ordenar para un campeonato de futbol en C no ordena

Tags: c, array-bidimensional, ordenamiento

Soy algo nuevo en C y mi profesor me asignó esta tarea:

Hacer un sistema con arreglos multidimensionales para recibir la tabla de clasificación de un campeonato de fútbol, teniendo en cuenta que por partido ganado dan 3 puntos, partido empatado dan 1 punto y partido perdido ninguno. Imprimirlos ordenados según puntaje.

Trabajé en este código en C y no sé qué error cometo ya que me imprime sin ordenar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ordenar(int [][7], int tam, char[][15]);

int main(){
    char nomEquipo[100][15];
    int valores[100][7], i, j, tam;
    /*
    
    0. Ganados
    1. Empatados
    2. Perdidos
    3. Goles a favor
    4. Goles en contra
    5. Diferencia de goles
    6. Total de puntos
    
    */
    printf("\nDigite la cantidad de equipos\n");
    scanf("%i",&tam);

    for ( i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        
            printf("\nDigite el nombre del equipo: \n");
            scanf("%s",nomEquipo[i]);
            printf("\nDigite los partidos ganados: \n");
            scanf("%i",&valores[i][0]);
            printf("\nDigite los partidos empatados: \n");
            scanf("%i",&valores[i][1]);
            printf("\nDigite los partidos perdidos: \n");
            scanf("%i",&valores[i][2]);
            printf("\nDigite los goles a favor: \n");
            scanf("%i",&valores[i][3]);
            printf("\nDigite los goles en contra: \n");
            scanf("%i",&valores[i][4]);
            valores[i][5]=valores[i][3]-valores[i][4];
            valores[i][6]=(valores[i][0]*3)+(valores[i][1]*1);
        
    }
    
    //Impimir arreglo sin ordenar

    printf("Nombres  |  P.G.  |  P.E.  |  P.P.  |  G.F.  |  G.C.  |  D.G.  |  Pts.\n");

    for ( i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",nomEquipo[i]);
        for ( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            printf("    %i    ",valores[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    
    
    printf("Escriba cualquier tecla para ordenar los equipos\n\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    #ifdef __linux__
    system("clear");
    #elif _WIN32
    system("cls");
    #endif

    ordenar(valores,tam,nomEquipo);

    return 0;
}

void ordenar(int arr[][7], int tam, char nom[][15]){
    int j, k, km1, aux[7];
    char auxNom[15];
    for ( j = 0; j < tam; j++)
    {
        for ( k = 1; k < tam; k++)
        {
            if(arr[k-1][6]<arr[k][6]){
                km1=k-1;
                //0
                aux[0]=arr[km1][0];
                arr[km1][0]=arr[k][0];
                arr[k][0]=aux[0];
                //1
                aux[1]=arr[km1+1][1];
                arr[km1+1][1]=arr[k+1][1];
                arr[k+1][1]=aux[1];
                //2
                aux[2]=arr[km1+2][2];
                arr[km1+2][2]=arr[k+2][2];
                arr[k+2][2]=aux[2];
                //3
                aux[3]=arr[km1+3][3];
                arr[km1+3][3]=arr[k+3][3];
                arr[k+3][3]=aux[3];
                //4
                aux[4]=arr[km1+4][4];
                arr[km1+4][4]=arr[k+4][4];
                arr[k+4][4]=aux[4];
                //5
                aux[5]=arr[km1+5][5];
                arr[km1+5][5]=arr[k+5][5];
                arr[k+5][5]=aux[5];
                //6
                aux[6]=arr[km1+6][6];
                arr[km1+6][6]=arr[k+6][6];
                arr[k+6][6]=aux[6];
                //nombres
                strcpy(auxNom,nom[km1]);
                strcpy(nom[km1],nom[k]);
                strcpy(nom[k],auxNom);
            }
        }
        
    }

    //Imprimir arreglo ordenado

    printf("Nombres  |  P.G.  |  P.E.  |  P.P.  |  G.F.  |  G.C.  |  D.G.  |  Pts.\n");

    for ( k = 0; k < tam; k++)
    {
        printf("%s ",nom[k]);
        for ( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            printf("    %i    ",arr[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    
}
```

No sé realmente si lo estoy haciendo bien o si habría una manera más limpia o sencilla de ordenarlos usando arrays bidimensionales(sin embargo, si existe una manera de ordenar estos datos usando structs en vez de arrays igual me podría servir).

Desconozco si este es el tema o el lugar donde puedo consultar, de todas maneras agradezco a quien lo lea que se haya tomado el tiempo de hacerlo, aun si no encuentra una solución a mi problema :D

Comment: Te has complicado demasiado. Lo mas simple es crear una estructura denominada `Equipo` y ahí agregas los campos `nombre`, `partidos_ganados`, etc. Posteriormente, debes crear un array de estructuras y luego invocas a la función [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) (esta función ordenará los elementos del array). Eso sí, tendrás que definir una función de comparación, en la cual, indicará el criterio de ordenación, en este caso, es ordenar según el puntaje y de forma descendente supongo.

Comment: Dale muchas gracias voy a intentarlo

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? Tu profesor te deja usar las funciones que vienen en la biblioteca estandar de C como qsort? Me confirmas y te doy una respuesta con respecto a la solucion que dije anteriormente..